# how to change the shortcut name of the popup menu item on the taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

how to change the shortcut name of the popup menu item on the taskbar(the red circle mark)

I try to change the solution name and project name but nothing changes

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0):

I guess it may at the Project > property > application > information properties

The title or the report or the name or something setting here?

(It should be the title in the detail setting..?)